# Position of a confirmBox

Tags: css, positioning

I was using absolute inside relative positioning in order to position the confirmBox. Since the page consists of a lot of content, the height of the page is very large. The confirmBox is positioned in the center of the page, but not in the center of the screen. Since the confirmBox can be opened at several points through several links on the web page, positioning of confirmBox in the center of the screen ( and not in the center of the page ) is required. How can I achieve that?

**CSS**

```
#confirmBox {
background:#fff;
border:1px solid #80686f;
border-radius:5px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px #766A65;
 -moz-box-shadow:0 8px 6px -6px #766A65;
box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px #766A65;
font-size:15px;
height:217px;
position:absolute;
text-align:center;
z-index:109;
width:400px;
top:50%;
left:50%;
margin-top:-108px;
margin-left:-200px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div style="position:relative">
<div id="confirmBox">
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: try using  "fixed" instead of absolute

Comment: Please put your answer in the answer section, so that I can give a vote up!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using "fixed" instead of absolute

Answer (score 1):

Use `fixed` instead of `absolute`, you cannot place an element in the center on the whole page using absolute. Check this CSS, I gave **top|right|bottom|left** **0px** it will bring the box in the center both horizontal and vertically.

```
#confirmBox {
border:1px solid #80686f;
height:217px;
position:fixed;
text-align:center;
z-index:109;
width:400px;
margin:auto;
left:0px;
right:0px;
bottom:0px;
top:0px;
}
```

Fiddle : JsFiddle isn't working, check the JsBin example (output) http://jsbin.com/uxafal/1/
.To view the code http://jsbin.com/uxafal/1/edit